# jQuery UI Layout: Set which pane must be closed everytime that a specific slide button is clicked

Tags: jquery-ui-layout

I'm using [JQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) and I did not find an answer in official documentation....

I have an UI Layout, with a noth pane and a south one divided in west and east. East is divided in north and south.
When I click on slider button to completely close a pane, is always the pane that I want to hide that is hidden, except for east pane in which is closed its north child while I want to hide south one.

How can I set which pane must be closed everytime that I click a specific slide button?

Thank you.